# ASP.NET MVC: StyleBundle IncludeDirectory & CssRewriteUrlTransform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, system.web.optimization, stylebundle

I have the same problem as many that my images are not resolved when I bundle my CSS-Stylesheets.

Now I found some SO-Answers that suggest using `new CssRewriteUrlTransform()` as second parameter for the "Include"-Method of a new StyleBundle-Object. [This one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277614/asp-net-mvc-cssrewriteurltransform-multiple-arguments)

I'm using IncludeDirectory because I have a directory where I can add files without having them to register somewhere (and they are many files which I don't want to list). But IncludeDirectory doesn't have an override to pass a CssRewriteUrlTransform-Object:

**Doesn't work:** `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/directives").IncludeDirectory("~/app/directives", "*.css", true));`

**I also tried:**

```
StyleBundle sb = new StyleBundle();
sb.Transforms.Add(new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

But Transforms are of Type IBundleTransform and I'm trying to pass an IItemTransform.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't find a better answer, I'll post my solution (which feels more like a workaround):

```
public class BundleConfig {
    private class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform {
        public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input) {
            //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765238/cssrewriteurltransform-with-or-without-virtual-directory
            return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);
        }
    }

    private static string MakeVirtualPath(string fromPhysPath, string withVirtualPath) {
        var res = fromPhysPath.Replace("\\", "/");
        var idx = res.IndexOf(withVirtualPath.Replace("~", ""));
        res = "~" + res.Substring(idx);

        return res;
    }

    private static StyleBundle CreateStyleBundleForDir(string virtualPath) {
        StyleBundle res = new StyleBundle(virtualPath + "/bundle");

        string[] cssFilesPhysical = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath), "*.css", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        List<string> cssFilesVirtual = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in cssFilesPhysical) {
            res.Include(MakeVirtualPath(file, virtualPath), new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper());
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
        bundles.Add(CreateStyleBundleForDir("~/app/custom"));
    }
}
```

I'm open for constructive citicism :)

Comment: If your images are in a static folder (say, Content > Images), your paths will resolve correctly with the default transforms if your CSS rules use an absolute path (something like `/content/images/foo.png`).

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks for your input. However, this is not correct: If you have a virtual application in IIS then "/" will point to the host, not the virtual application directory and absolute paths are broken as well. See the link I provided in the comment of the code. This person had the same problem and the answerer points to the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

Add this extension method to BundleConfig and use it as

```
new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/all.css")
   .InclDir("~/WebResources/libref/minton/css", "*.css");
```

Code:

```
private static void InclDir(this StyleBundle bundles, string virtualPath, string pattern, bool includeSubDir = false)
{
    var vpath = virtualPath.TrimEnd('/');
    var ppath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(vpath);
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(ppath, pattern, includeSubDir ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var vfp = virtualPath + "/" + file.Substring(ppath.Length + 1).Replace("\\", "/");
        bundles.Include(vfp, new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
    }
```